# ifconfig weirdly returns exit code 1

Tags: networking, java, ifconfig

I am executing the following command to find the MAC Address of eth0

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

I have a java wrapper which just calls the script containing only the above command.
If I run the java code it works fine with the above command executing successfully and outputting the MAC address.

The problem is when it is run under tomcat the Process executing the script sometime exits with exitcode 1 and output contains blank value.

Weird as it may sound but restarting the tomcat service and then trying to execute the script works fine giving the proper MAC Address. But later again it starts giving the same problem.

What is the possible solution for this ? Let me know if you want more information.

Comment: Why not just `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address` ?

Comment: Also why don't you [get MAC Address in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress()) ?

Comment: is the path /sys/class/net/eth0/address same for all the Linux Flavours ?

Comment: Also have not used java as we need to control the interface which it is connected to. Here I have used eth0 but that could change depending on requirement. And just changing the script will be simple enough and not require tomcat restart.

Comment: /sys/class is part of linux kernel since v2.5.

Comment: If you want solution of exact problem, I suggest you to move question to stackoverflow, as I understand problem in Java code or tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the actual problem.
When the process was running under tomcat the '/sbin' path was not present in the $PATH the tomcat was using.
You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673315).